# Magento Rest API Error missing media_gallery

Tags: api, magento, rest

I have completed setting up the Magento Rest API and been able to retrieve a list of product  without any errors using the API Example code Magento provides. However when I try to use the create a simple product example provided at  http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html#RESTAPIIntroduction-Overview 
I get the below error.

{"messages":{"error":[{"code":400,"message":"Missing \"media_gallery\" in request."}

I have looked everywhere and can't seem to find out how to fix the error. I don't see any reference here http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/Resources/Products/products.html#RESTAPI-Resource-Products-HTTPMethod-POST-products saying media_gallery is required in the request.

Can anyone shed some light on this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking that up as well, but you can always modify that attribute in magento's administration and just turn it off (catalog/attributes/manage attributes), as in make it NOT required.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks!  Having same problem with 1.8.  At first in Manage Attributes all I saw was "gallery" (vs. "media_gallery"), and it's already set to not required.  BUT I hadn't noticed there's paging, it's on page 2, Doh!